# Newbie issue? gdal install failing: Xcode and or CLT are misconfigured

Tags: gdal

I've worked out several sets of problems in installing the libraries for working with D3 and geographic data, but every time I just get to another challenge on this yellow brick road. At least it seems that way after slogging through the installs. I've been to the homebew wikis and many webpages of people who document how they do install on real machines, not 'greenroom' machines

Other people have had similar problems, but I can't see a problem that matches this:

Trying to install gdal (on Mac OS X 10,8.4) following the bost.ocks.org/mike/map guide using 
brew install gdal and trying to parse all kinds of errors and solutions others have logged.

I get the following error message now when I run `brew install gdal`:
    gcc-4.2 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/libxml2-py.o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/libxml.o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/types.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/lib -lxml2 -lm -lz -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/libxml2mod.so
    Your Xcode and or CLT are mis-configured. Try some or all of the following:
        xcodebuild -license
        sudo xcode-select -switch /path/to/Xcode.app
    error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

I ran xcodebuild -license which completed without an error; then retried brew install gdal again and got the same error. So I ran sudo xcode-select -switch /path/to/Xcode.app and got this message, which puts me back at the proverbial square 1:

```
xcode-select: Error: An error occurred while trying to -switch to '/path/to/Xcode.app'. (No such file or directory).
```

What does that message mean? What file or directory is the error referring to? This is what I can't find anywhere on stackoverflow.

Thanks much and in advance,
Francis

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install gdal then I recommend KyngChaos' installer. It will put everything in as a framework. This doesn't really answer the specific question you asked but it perhaps gives you what you were trying to achieve (I hope).